# ASP.NET MVC - Persist Login across Domains

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, multi-tenant

I am using Owin Authentication for my ASP.NET Mult-teneted network of websites.  Although all sites across the network share a common database (with users, etc), each site can have its own domain (sort of like Stackoverflow).

I would like to allow a user to login to one site and have that authentication persist across all sites so that they do not have to login again.

Currently, this is how I initialize authentication:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ConfigStartup))]
namespace Yeack
{
    public partial class ConfigStartup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder Application)
        {
            public void ConfigureAuthentication(IAppBuilder Application)
            {
                Application.CreatePerOwinContext<RepositoryManager>((x, y) => new RepositoryManager(new SiteDatabase(), x, y));

                Application.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    LoginPath = new PathString("/login"),
                    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<UserManager, User, int>(
                            validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                            regenerateIdentityCallback: (manager, user) => user.GenerateClaimsAsync(manager),
                            getUserIdCallback: (claim) => int.Parse(claim.GetUserId()))
                    }
                });

                Application.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and I have disabled forms authentication in the Web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None">
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The user logs in using the following:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = Persistent }, Profile.User.GenerateClaims(this));
```

And logged out like this:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie);
```

What's the easiest method of enabling cross-domain authentication?

Comment: for this you have to write the OWIN authentication middleware have look in to this link https://coding.abel.nu/2014/05/whats-this-owin-stuff-about/

Comment: This just seems like overkill to me...isn't there a way of having the OWIN Authentication provider create one cookie that can be used by multiple domains?  For instance, maybe if I set the CookieDomain??

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cookie using the cookie domain as `.stackoverflow.com` so that if i login to app.stackoverflow.com and then go on to the area51.stackoverflow.com, i would be still authenticated.

The cookie with a wild card in the domain "." will do the trick. But make sure that you use the http only cookie and secure cookie to avoid cookie hijacking.

sample code

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
  AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
  LoginPath = "/Account/Logon",
  CookieDomain = ".stackoverflow.com"
});
```

HTH